# Hide last items from menu when overflow

Tags: html, css, menu, overflow

How to do a menu with CSS that the lasts items will hide when the width of screen is lower than menu.

```
 <style>
    #container { width: 800px; }
    #container li { width : 200px;}
    </style>
    <div id="container">
    <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

It's possible to hide the Option 3 when the screen size is lower than 800px?

To be perfect: it's possible to change the Option 3 for "More" button to show the Option 3 and other possibles options (4, 5, 6....) when click it?

Comment: You need javascript for this. CSS cannot detect overflow

Comment: Can you post an example? No problem to use javascript